# SteamCMD and Family Sharing on dedicated server

Tags: steam, linux, steam-family-sharing, steamcmd

I'm upgrading to a new server soon and would like to make this one a bit more secure than my last one. Since many of the game server binaries I want to install require the game to have been brought, it means I need to log in everytime I want to update them. This make auto-updating difficult because I have Steam Guard enabled and I don't really want to leave my password in game's update scripts.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a second Steam account that I could do Steam Family Sharing with which would allow me to update the game servers which would save having to purchase the games twice.

If this is possible, how could in achieve this on GUI-less server?
AFAIK, Family Sharing can only be enabled in the Steam desktop GUI and I think only works on that particular machine, but I'm unsure of its possible and would like an answer for this. I feel this could help others too with the same question.

Comment: What about logging in once in `Steam>` prompt? Just run `steamcmd`, then `login <username>`, it will ask you for password and 2-factor authorisation. Then just `exit`. It will cache your credentials the same way Steam client does. Later you can just run `steamcmd +login <username> +...`. No password required in update scripts.

Comment: @Piotr I always get a cache miss when loading the scripts... Is that because I haven't signed in before running a script in the way you mentioned?

Comment: And how did you log in? I tested both my method in first comment and `steamcmd +login <username> +exit` and they both asked for password and 2-factor authorisation first time only. Later it just used cached credentials.

Comment: I just logged in using that method, but it still asks for a password when I run my update script for the game/s... I tried removing the `login <username>` from the update script too, but that doesn't help either.